# in keras, how can apply filter ( where ) funtion?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

like filter funtion in functools package, i want to find element over 0.5 in tensor.

this is code for that, but not work .

```
def pred_overhalf(y_true, y_pred):

    return K.count_params( filter( lambda x : x > 0.5 , y_pred ) )
model.compile(optimizer = "adam" , loss = "mse", metrics = [ pred_overhalf])
```

is there any way to solve this problem? I search keras backend documentation, but i cant find any solution

Comment: Try using tf.where https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where

Answer (score 0):

```
def pred_overhalf(y_true,y_pred):
    out = K.greater(y_pred,0.5)
    out = K.cast(out,K.floatx())

    #option 1
    return K.mean(out) #fraction of items greater than 0.5

    #option 2
    return K.sum(out) #total count (beware: this will consider all samples)
```